# Can i add a callback to a BackgroundWorker that is already running?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, callback

Is it possible to add a callback to a background worker while it is running ?

```
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler( some callback );

bw.RunWorkerAsync();

bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler( some callback );
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can. but that won't be called I suppose

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks. Is there a way to put tasks in a queue ?

Comment: you can use a `Queue` class for this, add work items to it then process one by one. Another option is to use `BlockingCollection`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you  can as it's only  a subscription  to an event but you  can't run bw until he has completed the execution  of the first task

here an example to illustrate this the following code will show an `InvalidOperationException`  telling This *`BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently."`*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {                       
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork+=new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker2_DoWork);
            //at this line you get an InvalidOperationException
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();




        }

        void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            do
            {

            } while (true);
        }
        void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            do
            {

            } while (true);
        }
       }
```

As an  answer to your comment question

*`@SriramSakthivel Thanks. Is there a way to put tasks in a queue ?`*

yes you  can if you are using .net 4.0 you can use task with [**`ContinueWith`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and attach it to your UI 
taskScheduler it will have the same behavior as if you are using BackgroundWorker

```
private void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestButton.Enabled = false;
    var uiThreadScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    var backgroundTask = new Task(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    });

    var uiTask = backgroundTask.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        TestButton.Enabled = true;
    }, uiThreadScheduler);

    backgroundTask.Start();
}
```